# Magento 2 Error in browser console Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, ajax, console

I have developed site in **Magento 2.2.0** and created custom product listing page.

I have used add to cart functionality using ajax but in **console giving error:-**

> "VM1386:5 Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom"

Any help will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: please see this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11904

Comment: @PradipGarchar Thanks for help. 

But I have facing issue something different in my case. I have showing that console warning after add to cart ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing add to cart issue after products loaded from ajax. I simply called catalogAddToCart function in my js success function and it worked.
Please try this, hope it will resolve your issue.

```
jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
```